# Unable to get Spring - Angular application deployed on Google cloud

Tags: docker-compose, google-kubernetes-engine

I have an application with Spring backend and Angular frontend. I am using docker-compose and it is creating 2 containers.

I have bridge network, so locally I am able to test.

Now I want to deploy to Google Cloud.

Question: (1) Do I need to create any gcp specific yaml file?

The cluster I created seems not good enough, Using GKE in this case

> Does not have minimum availability

I haven't seen any examples where spring and angular are deployed using CloudRun individually. But is this possible?

I desperately need to deploy my containers. IS there a way?

**Edit:**

The backend spring is able to talk to CloudSQL (answered in another post)

The angular app is not running because it doesnt know upstream host

```
nginx-py-sha256-2
2021/07/14 15:21:13 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "appserver:2623" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:2
```

In my docker compose -

```
services:
  # App backend service
  appserver:
    container_name: appserver
    image: appserver
  pui:
    container_name: nginx-py
    image: nginx-py
```

and my nginx.conf refers as appserver

The image I push is

> docker push eu.gcr.io/myapp/appserver

what name should I use in nginx.conf so that it can identify host  upstream? nice If I can disable prefix

[GCP Kubernetes workload "Does not have minimum availability"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53452120/gcp-kubernetes-workload-does-not-have-minimum-availability) is unanswered. so not a duplicate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GCP Kubernetes workload "Does not have minimum availability"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53452120/gcp-kubernetes-workload-does-not-have-minimum-availability)

Comment: @Pit because of cloudsql database connectivity issue, (not enabled by default), nodes were not starting. So I think its not a real unavailability issue (anyways sorted now)

Answer (score 1):

You have a container for the backend and a front end with static file. the best pattern for that is:

- Use Cloud Run for your backend
- Use [Cloud Storage for the frontend](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website) (static files) (make the bucket publicly accessible)
- Use a load balancer where you route the static request to the bucket backend, and the [backend request to Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/serverless-neg-concepts)

And, of course, forgot Docker Compose.

---

Note: if you have a container for your frontend, with a webserver (Angular server, NGINX or something else) you can deploy it on Cloud Run also, but you will pay processing for nothing. Cloud Storage is a better solution.

In both cases, a load balancer is recommended to avoid CORS issue. And in addition, you will be able to add CDN on the load balancer if you need it in your business

Comment: There are so many options. make war file with spring+ng and deploy to APp engine...and struggle connecting to db. So I have to make a clear goal - use GKE and deploy my docker compose images, and let them talk. Now question is why my nginx.conf doesnt know upstream "appserver". Should I use localhost instead?

Comment: I am bundling frontend into backend and creating war. My Development environment completely changed - No longer using Docker. I do have problems executing tests that need a container like tomcat (now using editor for such tests)