# Google Cloud Kubernetes Engine "gke-deployment" not found while running github actions

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, github-actions, gke-networking

I'm trying to deploy my code to GKE using github actions and when I run the action it says that service and deployment is created but then gives off an error, also the deployment it created in the cloud has an error.

[image]

And this is the deployment it creates:

[image]

My deployment.yaml file:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-1
  labels:
    type: nginx  # <-- correct
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      type: nginx  # incorrect, remove the '-'
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        type: nginx  # incorrect, remove the '-' 
    spec:
        containers:
        - image: nginx:1.14
          name: renderer
          ports:
           - containerPort: 80
```

My service.yaml:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-3-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
```

I just want to simply deploy my C++ code to kubernetes engine so I can experiment with it. I'm trying to push an ubuntu 20.04 image to europe-west1.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53452120/gcp-kubernetes-workload-does-not-have-minimum-availability) says that I must change the zone to fix the cloud's deployment's error but I'm not sure whether it will fix my problem or not and I don't know how to properly change it.

Comment: Have you tried changing the cluster zone ? You can particularly select cluster and workload zone seperately.

Comment: You cannot change a GKE cluster zone. You have to delete the cluster and create it again in the new zone.

What's the error you get ? If you click on the nginx deployment in that page you have in the screenshot and go into the events tab what do you see ?

Comment: It would be much better if you can share the workflow file as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So appereantly, for anyone facing this issue, you have to change the name of your `DEPLOYMENT_NAME` variable name inside your google.yaml file to your deployments name so it is the same as `metadata: name: "---"` inside your deployment.yaml, in my case I changed my `DEPLOYMENT_NAME` into nginx-1 to fix the issue.